# Why does NodeJS not always work on all platforms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, macos

I dont understand, I thought it was just javascript essentially. When I use nodejs packages, will i have to check for which system they were written? I read things like this sometimes, but I do not understand why and how this should be so, since it is javascript on should work on all platforms? Wrong?

Comment: The packages themselves should work on any OS/platform. The node server though, might be different. But at the end of the line, if a package doesn't work, the platform shouldn't be the issue as far as I know.

Comment: When a package is OS specific, it is often because they are doing OS specific things, like calling the system shell directly and invoking a X or Y program to do its task. A well made package, using the default functions (like `fs.readFile` and not calling `cat` and parsing the output) will work on any OS.